# Objective C: How to remove a white background from a JPG image without losing edge quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimage

So I have many jpg images with white backgrounds that I am loading into my app, and I would like to remove the white backgrounds programmatically.  I have a function that does this, but it causes some jagged edges around each image.  Is there a way that I can blend these edges to achieve smooth edges?

My current method:

```
-(UIImage *)changeWhiteColorTransparent: (UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef rawImageRef=image.CGImage;

    const CGFloat colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    CGImageRef maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), maskedImageRef);
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

I know that I can change the color masking values, but I don't think any combination will produce a smooth picture with no white background.

Heres an example:

[image]

That method also removes extra pixels within the images that are close to white:

[image]

I think the ideal method would change the alpha of white pixels according to how close to pure white they are instead of just removing them all.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is called chroma key compositing. It may be simpler to use a kernel processing algorithm rather than doing per pixel calculations. The documentation for CIFilter has an [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html). GPUImage also has examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
#import "UIImage+FloodFill.h"
//https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

#define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
#define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
#define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
#define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )
#define A(x) ( Mask8(x >> 24) )
#define RGBAMake(r, g, b, a) ( Mask8(r) | Mask8(g) << 8 | Mask8(b) << 16 | Mask8(a) << 24 )

@interface UIImage (BackgroundRemoval)
//Simple Removal
- (UIImage *)floodFillRemoveBackgroundColor;
@end

@implementation UIImage (BackgroundRemoval)
- (UIImage*) maskImageWithMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

  CGImageRef maskImageRef = [maskImage CGImage];

  // create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
  CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  if (mainViewContentContext==NULL)
  return NULL;

  CGFloat ratio = 0;

  ratio = maskImage.size.width/ self.size.width;

  if(ratio * self.size.height < maskImage.size.height) {
    ratio = maskImage.size.height/ self.size.height;
  }

  CGRect rect1  = { {0, 0}, {maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height} };
  CGRect rect2  = { {-((self.size.width*ratio)-maskImage.size.width)/2 , -((self.size.height*ratio)-maskImage.size.height)/2}, {self.size.width*ratio, self.size.height*ratio} };


  CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, rect1, maskImageRef);
  CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, rect2, self.CGImage);


  // Create CGImageRef of the main view bitmap content, and then
  // release that bitmap context
  CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
  CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);

  UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];

  CGImageRelease(newImage);

  // return the image
  return theImage;
}

- (UIImage *)floodFillRemove{
  //1
  UIImage *processedImage = [self floodFillFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withColor:[UIColor magentaColor] andTolerance:0];

  CGImageRef inputCGImage=processedImage.CGImage;
  UInt32 * inputPixels;
  NSUInteger inputWidth = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
  NSUInteger inputHeight = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

  NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
  NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

  NSUInteger inputBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * inputWidth;

  inputPixels = (UInt32 *)calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, sizeof(UInt32));

  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(inputPixels, inputWidth, inputHeight, bitsPerComponent, inputBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight), inputCGImage);

  //2

  for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < inputHeight; j++) {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < inputWidth; i++) {
      UInt32 * currentPixel = inputPixels + (j * inputWidth) + i;
      UInt32 color = *currentPixel;

      if (R(color) == 255 && G(color) == 0 && B(color) == 255) {
        *currentPixel = RGBAMake(0, 0, 0, A(0));
        }else{
          *currentPixel = RGBAMake(R(color), G(color), B(color), A(color));
        }
      }
  }
  CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

  //3

  UIImage * maskImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  CGContextRelease(context);
  free(inputPixels);

  UIImage *result = [self maskImageWithMask:maskImage];

  //4

  return result;
}

@end
```

what if your image with gradient background?
use below code for that.

```js
- (UIImage *)complexReoveBackground{

  GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self];

  GPUImagePrewittEdgeDetectionFilter *filter = [[GPUImagePrewittEdgeDetectionFilter alloc] init];
  [filter setEdgeStrength:0.04];

  [stillImageSource addTarget:filter];
  [filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
  [stillImageSource processImage];

  UIImage *resultImage = [filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

  UIImage *processedImage = [resultImage floodFillFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withColor:[UIColor magentaColor] andTolerance:0];

  CGImageRef inputCGImage=processedImage.CGImage;
  UInt32 * inputPixels;
  NSUInteger inputWidth = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
  NSUInteger inputHeight = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

  NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
  NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

  NSUInteger inputBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * inputWidth;

  inputPixels = (UInt32 *)calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, sizeof(UInt32));

  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(inputPixels, inputWidth, inputHeight, bitsPerComponent, inputBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight), inputCGImage);

  for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < inputHeight; j++) {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < inputWidth; i++) {
      UInt32 * currentPixel = inputPixels + (j * inputWidth) + i;
      UInt32 color = *currentPixel;

      if (R(color) == 255 && G(color) == 0 &&   B(color) == 255) {
        *currentPixel = RGBAMake(0, 0, 0, A(0));
      }else{
        *currentPixel = RGBAMake(0, 0, 0, 255);
      }
    }
  }
  CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
  UIImage * maskImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  CGContextRelease(context);
  free(inputPixels);

  GPUImagePicture *maskImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:maskImage];

  GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
  [blurFilter setBlurRadiusInPixels:0.7];
  [maskImageSource addTarget:blurFilter];
  [blurFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
  [maskImageSource processImage];

  UIImage *blurMaskImage = [blurFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
  //return blurMaskImage;
  UIImage *result = [self maskImageWithMask:blurMaskImage];

  return result;
}
```

You can download the sample code from here [sample code](https://github.com/darkcl/Background-Removal-Example)

Comment: I know this is late but thanks! Using the first code snippet worked great after playing with the flood tolerance and adding in some extra code to remove the excess magenta coloring.

Comment: The correct link to sample [here](https://github.com/darkcl/Background-Removal-Example)